# Can I disable OS X Lion's "You are not connected to the internet" dialog?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion

As far as I can remember, this was introduced or has become more prominent in OS X Lion.  When I open my Macbook and a known internet connection (WiFi, LAN or otherwise), I get a "You are not connected to the internet" pop-up dialog.

This is starting to get really frustrating when trying to work in places where I know I have no internet connection!

Does anyone know how to disable this pop-up?

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck *Ask to join new networks* in the Network preference pane:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I already have that box unchecked and still see the "You're not connected..." dialog.